# How to compare two database table fields in YII2?

Tags: yii2

Suppose we have a table named `"appointment"` which have fields `"id"`, `"date1"` and `"date2"`.
Preferably using ActiveRecord, I want to achieve this sql statement:

```
select * from appointment where date1 <> date2
```

Is it possible to do this using Activerecord methods for e.g. (Appointment::find()) or should I pass solid SQL codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use an sql expression to pass this condition to any given query

```
Appointment::find()->where(new \yii\db\Expression('`date1` <> `date2`'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may use something like this,

```
Appointment::find()->andWhere('date1 <> date2')
                   ->all();
```

Comment: Yes, this also works. but  we'd better to use the concept expression, as in documentation mentioned: 
"Expression represents a DB expression that does not need escaping or quoting. Expression objects are mainly created for passing raw SQL expressions to methods of yii\db\Query, yii\db\ActiveQuery, and related classes"